# Time-based sliding window

Tags: c++, machine-learning, time-series

I am looking for materials to properly write c++ class for time-based sliding window.
I am doing machine learning on times series using discriminative algorithm (svm) and I need to make prediction on new streaming series then I need sliding window on different size and scale.
Thanks.

Comment: (grumble) Why on Earth i am doing this?! But, anyway, take a look - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096753/designing-a-fast-rolling-window-file-reader

Comment: sorry it's not c++ but I'll recommend not to reinvent the wheel and use: pandas (http://pandas.pydata.org/) for the timeseries and sklearn (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) for the svm. It's python but all performance critical parts are highly optimized in non-python :)

Comment: Since I am processing streaming video for webcam I would like to have more hints on how to properly design multiscale sliding window to make prediction (using learned SVM). Thks.